# QMediaPlayer can't play MP3's

Tags: c++, qt, media-player

I need to build a simple mediaplayer for university using QT and I hit a wall. 
Everytime I try to play a file (mp3, wav, doensn't matter) I'll just get

`DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 80070020`

with every file. The files are not broken, every other player can play them. 
It used to work (reading the tags, displaying them and actually playing the file) up until I would go ahead and add a album-artwork to display. The standard QMediaPlayer is used in this project.

I don't quite know where it might have gone wrong, it just stopped working all of a sudden...
I'm on QT 5.2.3 if that's of any help.

Thanks!

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code that generates this error.

Comment: Which lines of code are actually relevant? I'm sorry, I'm really new to programming so I have no idea what might help you out...

Comment: Did that. But the songs sometimes play, sometimes they do not. This can't be a codec related problem I take it?

Comment: Who the hell knows, for me, on windows 7, Qt barely plays some wav files, and not all, and using the ancient and uberly latent MME, it seems media support is close to abysmal.